# Tensorflow: function.defun with a a while loop in the body is throwing shape error

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, ubuntu-16.04

I am using a while loop to calculate a cost function for memory reasons. When calculating the gradient, tensorflow will store Nm tensors where Nm is the number of iterations in my while loop (this cuases the same memory issues I had with the original energy functions). I do not want that as I don't have enough memory. **So I want to register a new op along with a gradient function that both use a while loop**. However I am having issues with **using function.defun and a while loop**. To simplify things, I have a small test example below:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.python.framework import ops
from tensorflow.python.ops import array_ops
from tensorflow.python.ops import sparse_ops
from tensorflow.python.framework import function


def _run(tensor):
    with tf.Session() as sess:
         sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
         res = sess.run(tensor)
    return res


@function.Defun(tf.float32,tf.float32,func_name ='tf_test_log')#,grad_func=tf_test_logGrad)
def tf_test_log(t_x,t_y):
    #N = t_x.shape[0].value
    condition = lambda i,m1: i<N

    def body(index,x):
        #return[(index+1),tf.concat([x, tf.expand_dims(tf.exp( tf.add( t_x[:,index],t_y[:,index]) ),1)   ],1 ) ]
        return[(index+1),tf.add(x, tf.exp( tf.add( t_x[:,0],t_y[:,0]) )    ) ]

    i0      = tf.constant(0,dtype=tf.int32)
    m0      = tf.zeros([N,1],dType)


    ijk_0   = [i0,m0]

    L,t_log_x = tf.while_loop(condition,body,ijk_0,
                     shape_invariants=[i0.get_shape(), 
                                       tf.TensorShape([N,None])]
                                        )
    return t_log_x



dType = tf.float32
N     = np.int32(100)

t_N   = tf.constant(N,dtype = tf.int32)
t_x   = tf.constant(np.random.randn(N,N),dtype = dType)
t_y   = tf.constant(np.random.randn(N,N),dtype = dType)
ys = _run(tf_test_log(t_x,t_y))
```

I then try to test the new op:

I get a Value error: **The shape for while/Merge_1:0 is not an invariant for the loop. It enters the loop with shape (100, ?), but has shape  after one iteration. Provide shape invariants using either the `shape_invariants` argument of tf.while_loop or set_shape() on the loop variables.**

Note that calling

1. If i use a concatenate operation (instead of the add operation that gets returned by my while loop), I do not get any issues.
2. However, If I do not set N as a global variable (i.e. I do N = t_x.shape[0]) inside the body of the tf_test_log function, I get a Value error.

   `ValueError: Cannot convert a partially known TensorShape to a Tensor: (?, 1)`

**What is wrong with my code?** Any help is greatly appreciated!

I am using python 3.5 on ubuntu 16.04 and tensorflow 1.4

full output:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
~/Documents/TheEffingPhDHatersGonnaHate/PAM/defun_while.py in <module>()
     51 t_x   = tf.constant(np.random.randn(N,N),dtype = dType)
     52 t_y   = tf.constant(np.random.randn(N,N),dtype = dType)
---> 53 ys = _run(tf_test_log(t_x,t_y))
     54 
     55 

~/environments/tf_1_4_gpu/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/function.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    503 
    504   def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
--> 505     self.add_to_graph(ops.get_default_graph())
    506     args = [ops.convert_to_tensor(_) for _ in args] + self._extra_inputs
    507     ret, op = _call(self._signature, *args, **kwargs)

~/environments/tf_1_4_gpu/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/function.py in add_to_graph(self, g)
    484   def add_to_graph(self, g):
    485     """Adds this function into the graph g."""
--> 486     self._create_definition_if_needed()
    487 
    488     # Adds this function into 'g'.

~/environments/tf_1_4_gpu/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/function.py in _create_definition_if_needed(self)
    319     """Creates the function definition if it's not created yet."""
    320     with context.graph_mode():
--> 321       self._create_definition_if_needed_impl()
    322 
    323   def _create_definition_if_needed_impl(self):

~/environments/tf_1_4_gpu/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/function.py in _create_definition_if_needed_impl(self)
    336       # Call func and gather the output tensors.
    337       with vs.variable_scope("", custom_getter=temp_graph.getvar):
--> 338         outputs = self._func(*inputs)
    339 
    340       # There is no way of distinguishing between a function not returning

~/Documents/TheEffingPhDHatersGonnaHate/PAM/defun_while.py in tf_test_log(t_x, t_y)
     39     L,t_log_x = tf.while_loop(condition,body,ijk_0,
     40                          shape_invariants=[i0.get_shape(), 
---> 41                                            tf.TensorShape([N,None])]
     42                                             )
     43     return t_log_x

~/environments/tf_1_4_gpu/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/control_flow_ops.py in while_loop(cond, body, loop_vars, shape_invariants, parallel_iterations, back_prop, swap_memory, name)
   2814     loop_context = WhileContext(parallel_iterations, back_prop, swap_memory)  # pylint: disable=redefined-outer-name
   2815     ops.add_to_collection(ops.GraphKeys.WHILE_CONTEXT, loop_context)
-> 2816     result = loop_context.BuildLoop(cond, body, loop_vars, shape_invariants)
   2817     return result
   2818 

~/environments/tf_1_4_gpu/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/control_flow_ops.py in BuildLoop(self, pred, body, loop_vars, shape_invariants)
   2638       self.Enter()
   2639       original_body_result, exit_vars = self._BuildLoop(
-> 2640           pred, body, original_loop_vars, loop_vars, shape_invariants)
   2641     finally:
   2642       self.Exit()

~/environments/tf_1_4_gpu/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/control_flow_ops.py in _BuildLoop(self, pred, body, original_loop_vars, loop_vars, shape_invariants)
   2619     for m_var, n_var in zip(merge_vars, next_vars):
   2620       if isinstance(m_var, ops.Tensor):
-> 2621         _EnforceShapeInvariant(m_var, n_var)
   2622 
   2623     # Exit the loop.

~/environments/tf_1_4_gpu/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/control_flow_ops.py in _EnforceShapeInvariant(merge_var, next_var)
    576           "Provide shape invariants using either the `shape_invariants` "
    577           "argument of tf.while_loop or set_shape() on the loop variables."
--> 578           % (merge_var.name, m_shape, n_shape))
    579   else:
    580     if not isinstance(var, (ops.IndexedSlices, sparse_tensor.SparseTensor)):

ValueError: The shape for while/Merge_1:0 is not an invariant for the loop. It enters the loop with shape (100, ?), but has shape <unknown> after one iteration. Provide shape invariants using either the `shape_invariants` argument of tf.while_loop or set_shape() on the loop variables.
```

Comment: The shape of the tf.add(...) tensor returned from the body seems to be confusing / not invariant. Do instead x = tf.add(...); x.set_shape(...); return index+1, x in your body and it should work.

Comment: @AlexandrePassos Thanks, when I do this it works. However, I still need to set N as being global. I have the updated code in an answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Alexandre Passos for the suggestion in the comment above!
The following piece of code is a modification of the original with a set_shape function added inside the body.

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.python.framework import ops
from tensorflow.python.ops import array_ops
from tensorflow.python.ops import sparse_ops
from tensorflow.python.framework import function

def _run(tensor):
    with tf.Session() as sess:
         sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
         res = sess.run(tensor)
    return res


@function.Defun(tf.float32,tf.float32,tf.float32,func_name ='tf_test_logGrad')
def tf_test_logGrad(t_x,t_y,grad):
     return grad



@function.Defun(tf.float32,tf.float32,func_name     ='tf_test_log')#,grad_func=tf_test_logGrad)
def tf_test_log(t_x,t_y):
    #N = t_x.shape[0].value
    condition = lambda i,m1: i<N

    def body(index,x):
        #return[(index+1),tf.concat([x, tf.expand_dims(tf.exp( tf.add(     t_x[:,index],t_y[:,index]) ),1)   ],1 ) ]
        x = tf.add(x, tf.exp( tf.add( t_x[:,0],t_y[:,0]) )    )
        x.set_shape([N])
        return[(index+1), x]

    i0      = tf.constant(0,dtype=tf.int32)
    m0      = tf.zeros([N],dType)


    ijk_0   = [i0,m0]

    L,t_log_x = tf.while_loop(condition,body,ijk_0,
                     shape_invariants=[i0.get_shape(), 
                                       tf.TensorShape([N])]
                                        )
    return t_log_x



dType = tf.float32
N     = np.int32(100)

t_N   = tf.constant(N,dtype = tf.int32)
t_x   = tf.constant(np.random.randn(N,N),dtype = dType)
t_y   = tf.constant(np.random.randn(N,N),dtype = dType)
ys = _run(tf_test_log(t_x,t_y))
```

**The Issue of global N still persists.**

You still need to set the shape of the loop tensors as a global variable **outside** of the defun decorator. If you try to get it from the shape of the inputs of the defun decorator, you get:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
~/environments/tf_1_4_gpu/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/array_ops.py in zeros(shape, dtype, name)
   1438       shape = tensor_shape.as_shape(shape)
-> 1439       output = constant(zero, shape=shape, dtype=dtype, name=name)
   1440     except (TypeError, ValueError):

~/environments/tf_1_4_gpu/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/constant_op.py in constant(value, dtype, shape, name, verify_shape)
    207       tensor_util.make_tensor_proto(
--> 208           value, dtype=dtype, shape=shape, verify_shape=verify_shape))
    209   dtype_value = attr_value_pb2.AttrValue(type=tensor_value.tensor.dtype)

~/environments/tf_1_4_gpu/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/tensor_util.py in make_tensor_proto(values, dtype, shape, verify_shape)
    379     # exception when dtype is set to np.int64
--> 380     if shape is not None and np.prod(shape, dtype=np.int64) == 0:
    381       nparray = np.empty(shape, dtype=np_dt)

~/environments/tf_1_4_gpu/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py in prod(a, axis, dtype, out, keepdims)
   2517     return _methods._prod(a, axis=axis, dtype=dtype,
-> 2518                           out=out, **kwargs)
   2519 

~/environments/tf_1_4_gpu/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy/core/_methods.py in _prod(a, axis, dtype, out, keepdims)
     34 def _prod(a, axis=None, dtype=None, out=None, keepdims=False):
---> 35     return umr_prod(a, axis, dtype, out, keepdims)
     36 

TypeError: __int__ returned non-int (type NoneType)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
~/Documents/TheEffingPhDHatersGonnaHate/PAM/defun_while.py in <module>()
     52 t_x   = tf.constant(np.random.randn(N,N),dtype = dType)
     53 t_y   = tf.constant(np.random.randn(N,N),dtype = dType)
---> 54 ys = _run(tf_test_log(t_x,t_y))
     55 
     56 

~/environments/tf_1_4_gpu/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/function.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    503 
    504   def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
--> 505     self.add_to_graph(ops.get_default_graph())
    506     args = [ops.convert_to_tensor(_) for _ in args] + self._extra_inputs
    507     ret, op = _call(self._signature, *args, **kwargs)

~/environments/tf_1_4_gpu/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/function.py in add_to_graph(self, g)
    484   def add_to_graph(self, g):
    485     """Adds this function into the graph g."""
--> 486     self._create_definition_if_needed()
    487 
    488     # Adds this function into 'g'.

~/environments/tf_1_4_gpu/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/function.py in _create_definition_if_needed(self)
    319     """Creates the function definition if it's not created yet."""
    320     with context.graph_mode():
--> 321       self._create_definition_if_needed_impl()
    322 
    323   def _create_definition_if_needed_impl(self):

~/environments/tf_1_4_gpu/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/function.py in _create_definition_if_needed_impl(self)
    336       # Call func and gather the output tensors.
    337       with vs.variable_scope("", custom_getter=temp_graph.getvar):
--> 338         outputs = self._func(*inputs)
    339 
    340       # There is no way of distinguishing between a function not returning

~/Documents/TheEffingPhDHatersGonnaHate/PAM/defun_while.py in tf_test_log(t_x, t_y)
     33 
     34     i0      = tf.constant(0,dtype=tf.int32)
---> 35     m0      = tf.zeros([N],dType)
     36 
     37 

~/environments/tf_1_4_gpu/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/array_ops.py in zeros(shape, dtype, name)
   1439       output = constant(zero, shape=shape, dtype=dtype, name=name)
   1440     except (TypeError, ValueError):
-> 1441       shape = ops.convert_to_tensor(shape, dtype=dtypes.int32, name="shape")
   1442       output = fill(shape, constant(zero, dtype=dtype), name=name)
   1443   assert output.dtype.base_dtype == dtype

~/environments/tf_1_4_gpu/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py in convert_to_tensor(value, dtype, name, preferred_dtype)
    834       name=name,
    835       preferred_dtype=preferred_dtype,
--> 836       as_ref=False)
    837 
    838 

~/environments/tf_1_4_gpu/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py in internal_convert_to_tensor(value, dtype, name, as_ref, preferred_dtype, ctx)
    924 
    925     if ret is None:
--> 926       ret = conversion_func(value, dtype=dtype, name=name, as_ref=as_ref)
    927 
    928     if ret is NotImplemented:

~/environments/tf_1_4_gpu/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/constant_op.py in _tensor_shape_tensor_conversion_function(s, dtype, name, as_ref)
    248   if not s.is_fully_defined():
    249     raise ValueError(
--> 250         "Cannot convert a partially known TensorShape to a Tensor: %s" % s)
    251   s_list = s.as_list()
    252   int64_value = 0

ValueError: Cannot convert a partially known TensorShape to a Tensor: (?,)
```

Comment: Yes, the defun decorator erases the shapes of the inputs, as the function definition itself is not supposed to depend on the input shape. Right now either having N as a global integer (not a tensor) defined outside the function is best _or_ do something like N = tf.shape(x)[0]